# Copy of Jutila's "On the divisor problem for short intervals"

Tags: analytic-number-theory, paper-request

M. Jutila's paper ''On the divisor problem for short intervals'', published on Ann. Univ. Turku. Ser. A I No. 186 (1984), is cited more than 30 times but I am unable to locate any copy. I am asking for help in obtaining a copy.

The full journal name is ''Annales Universitatis Turkuensis. Series A. I. Astronomica-Chemica-Physica-Mathematica''.

Comment: Email jutila@utu.fi maybe?

Comment: @kodlu Thanks, I will take that suggestion if I'll fail getting a copy in the next couple of days.